# Civi Event RSVPs

Tags: civievent

Is it possible to show how many spots are available for RSVPs/registration for events as people are registering on the website (in real time)? For example, say someone wants to register for "X" event, they go to our calendar event on the website, see we have 2 spaces left available but they want to purchase 4 tickets. As of now, they have no way of knowing until they enter how many tickets they would like to purchase.

Comment: what cms? for drupal you may be able to get a view block showing on the info and/or registration page showing how many places remain

Comment: It is drupal. So you think a view could be created to show registration totals? Good idea. I can give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

For sites using Drupal you should be able to get a view block showing on the info and/or registration page showing how many places remain - may require a bit of php in the view to do the subtraction of total places minus registered participants